# Espresso, pour starts dripping halfway?

Tags: espresso, coffee-machines

I have a Espresso machine (Rocket R58).

I'm curious why my pour starts to drip **halfway** the pull. Is there any **explanation** why **halfway** and not from the get-go?

*I do understand I need to go more coarse to fix this...*

Comment: Welcome! While coffee is in principle on topic here, we've found that [coffee.se] often has more specific advice on questions like this, so I'm migrating it there.

Comment: @Jefromi, awesome! Didn't know we have a coffee exchange! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the pre-infusion feature of your machine in conjunction with the grind you were using. From [their site](https://www.seattlecoffeegear.com/rocket-dual-boiler-r58-espresso-machine):

> Pre-Infusion: To extract the full flavor and aroma when you brew your espresso, the R58 has a dual pre-infusion system encompassing a working piston and static pre-infusion chamber.

Most machines that have this feature understand that the pre-infusion is done based on the amount of water that has flowed, not how much time has passed (which is a good thing). So, if the puck is too dense, it can take quite a bit of time.

Adjusting grind a bit should fix it.

Answer (score 4):

There may be some advice on this. My first will be to check the pressure as you can do this with your pretty machine. Please check if you are around 9 bars when pulling the shot.

One reason of delay is, it takes a while for the water to wet the grounds. So, it is normal to wait for a few seconds to see the first drops. However; if it is more than a few seconds, the most possible problems I can think of are:

- The pressure is not enough
- You have tamped so forcefully
- The grind is too fine

Comment: Thanks! It starts to flow between 3-5 seconds, and looks allright. But ½  way the shot (12-17 seconds), it suddenly starts to drip. The puck is also a bit mud-isch, maybe indeed its all about the grind (to fine).

Comment: Please check this [discussion](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/how-to-re-calibrate-an-espresso-machine-and-grinder-setup/1939#1939) for adjusting grind size. However, muddy puck may indicate insufficient amount of coffee. Please check if you use 7 to 8 grams of coffee per espresso shot (30 ml).