# "Untwist" the triple-shot program?

Tags: espresso-machine, starbucks

On one of the super-automatics at work (Starbucks Mastrena), we have a "twisted" triple-shot program where the single-shot portion is grinding longer than the double-shot portion. [My procedure](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/how-to-re-calibrate-an-espresso-machine-and-grinder-setup/1940#1940) isn't fixing it.

How can I trick its little brain to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I had an idea. It hasn't worked yet, but based on my theories, it *ought to work*.

To calibrate the triple-shot button when the single part is too long for the double part,

1. Queue-up several triples.
2. Just before it grinds for the single, crank up the grind 10 (or more) clicks finer.
3. Just before it grinds for the double, crank down the grind 10 (or more) clicks coarser.

This should exaggerate the problem so the little computer can "see" it, and apply whatever self-correction it may.